# Is is possible to force TFS to always give a conflict for particular file types

Tags: tfs, merge

We use TFS 2015 at work.  Some of our files are text based, but the merge tools don't work properly for them (the files are XML based).

Is there a way to configure TFS so that if 2 files of a particular extension require a merge, that TFS will always generate a file conflict?

This will allow humans to make the decision which file to take, rather than the computer silently merging and probably creating invalid files.

Answer (score 0):

As I know from the official document, it seems there isn’t a way to achieve it, you can compare the particular files manually before merging to make the decision which file to take, or disable **AutoResolve** by Clear the **Attempt to automatically resolve conflicts when they are generated** checkbox, (Tools --> Options -- > Source Control -- > Visual Studio Team Foundation Server).

You can also invoke the **Resolve Conflicts** dialog box using command-line client (tf.exe), so that you can tell Team Foundation Server how to deal with the conflict.

Here are the similar questions for your reference:

[TFS 2010 Merge Files Question: Can I force a conflict?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/305a6521-b835-4ab5-86cf-fbcd7f548307/tfs-2010-merge-files-question-can-i-force-a-conflict?forum=tfsversioncontrol)

[Force comparison of files when merging in Visual Studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202224/force-comparison-of-files-when-merging-in-visual-studio-2008)